# SpriteKit - The child of my node does not appear to be changing its zPosition attribute

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

my issue is, I've got a "2.5D" game where characters that come into contact with one another need to dynamically change their zPosition. I'm using physics bodies to achieve this.

It works OK with the characters, however, the shield they are holding (a child object) is not following suit even though I'm logging a correct change of zPosition attribute.

```
if (((firstNode.categoryBitMask & dudeCategory) != 0) && ((secondNode.categoryBitMask & shieldGuyCategory) !=0))
{
    if ((firstNode.node.position.y < secondNode.node.parent.position.y))
    {
        [secondNode.node.parent enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"shieldNode" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop){
            NSLog(@"Ooh I Say! Shield zPos = %f", node.zPosition);

            SKAction *zPos = [SKAction runBlock:^{
                node.zPosition = node.zPosition -200;

                NSLog(@"And now, %@ zPos = %f", node.name, node.zPosition);
                NSLog(@"But static NPC zPos = %f", firstNode.node.zPosition);
                NSLog(@"And finally, Shield-holder Guy zPos = %f", secondNode.node.parent.zPosition);
            }];

            [node runAction:zPos];
        }];

        secondNode.node.parent.zPosition = secondNode.node.parent.zPosition -200;
    }
}
```

Halp!

Comment: Why not set the zPosition directly instead of using `SKAction runBlock:`?

Comment: It was set directly in my original code, I thought maybe it required SKAction to explicitly change it, turns out it doesn't.

Comment: Great. Have added an answer.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was, it didn't work initially with: `node.zPosition = node.zPosition -200;` with no `SKAction runBlock:` at all. Stranger still is that NSLog reports a correct change but the game does not display it.

Comment: I might tweak the code so all 4 NSLogs reflects the node names too, just to be certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out I was setting the zPosition for the shield in its method. Removing that restores normal behaviour when the parent changes zPosition, having it declared explicitly seems to override the nested behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the zPosition using `SKAction runBlock:`, set it directly.

```
[secondNode.node.parent enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"shieldNode" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop){
        node.zPosition -= 200;
    }];
```